# Creating re-orderable card component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working my way through React, and I'm building a portfolio site. On the work page, I have 3 tiles, which will eventually be overlapping. When a card is clicked, it opens a side panel, and (hopefully) the active card goes to the front, pushing the others behind it to fill in the space.

I currently have the cards, or tabs working, I just need help with how to rearrange them on click.

This is the Tab.js component

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Tab extends Component {

  onClick = () => {
    const { label, onClick } = this.props;
    console.log('that tickles', {onClick})
    onClick(label);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onClick,
      props: {
        activeTab,
        label,
        position,
        inactivePosition,
        style
      },
    } = this;
    console.log(this)

    let className = 'tab-list-item';

    if (activeTab === label) { 
      className += ' tab-list-active';
    }

    return (
      <div
        style={style}
        className={className}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        {label}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tab;
```

The tabs.js component that brings things together

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './tabstyle.css'
import Tab from './tab.js';

class Tabs extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array).isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label,
    };
  }

  onClickTabItem = (tab) => {
    this.setState({ 
      activeTab: tab
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {
      onClickTabItem,
      props: {
        children,
        position,
      },
      state: {
        activeTab,
        inactiveTab1,
        inactiveTab2,
      }
    } = this;
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {children.map((child) => {
        const { label } = child.props;
          return (
            <Tab
              activeTab={activeTab}
              key={label}
              label={label}
              onClick={onClickTabItem}

            />
          );
      })} 
        <div className="tab-content">
          {children.map((child) => {
            if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined;
            return child.props.children;
          })}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}
export default Tabs;
```

the actual work page

```
export default function Work() {

    return (


        <React.Fragment >
           <Tabs>
                <div label="Example1" position='1'>
                what in the world
                </div>
                <div  label="Example2" position='2'>
                lorem ipsum
                </div>
                <div  label="Example3" position='3'>
                Nothing to see here, this tab is!
                </div>
            </Tabs> 
        </React.Fragment>
    );

}
```

```
}
.tab-list-item {
    background-color:#fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.tab-content {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(19, 47, 74);
    grid-area:1/13/span 9/ span 8;
    z-index: 5;
    padding:3em;
}


.tab-list-active {
    background-color: #f0f;


    grid-area: 2/3/span 4/ span 4;

}

.position2{
    grid-area:3/4/span 4/ span 4;

}

.position3{
    grid-area:4/5/span 4/ span 4;
}
```

In my mind, I pictured building an array, and simply having the first card be active, then when another card is clicked, that card is sent to position 0, and so on.

I hope that's everything. As I said, I'm pretty new to React, bit less new to vanilla JavaScript, but still pretty green. Any guidance would be massively appreciated, as I'm at a bit of an impasse at the moment.

For a working demo, I'm using AWS Amplify to host it temporarily https://master.d2wqg4b36m462q.amplifyapp.com/work

Comment: Hey Joseph and welcome to SO! Could you take a moment and fix the formatting errors in your question and also post a link to a working demo (such as a fiddle)?

Comment: Please paste tabstyle.css

Comment: Hey guys, thanks! I've added the Css file and a link to a working demo of the page

Comment: children is supposedly something that renders. An array itself will not render. And in order to render children you should just use `{children}`. If you want to use it as an array, simply pass an array of objects as a property to `Tabs` such as `tabs` e.g. `<Tabs tabs=[{ label: "abc" }] />` and then use it in `Tabs` and iterate over the property not the children.